# Does Alamofire support HTTP pipelining?

Tags: alamofire

We are about to pull the trigger and switch from AFNetworking to Alamofire and we just want to make sure that it is future proof.

One of the question is does it support HTTP pipelining?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does. 
You just have to override the `RequestAdapter` class, do `urlRequest.httpShouldUsePipelining = true` inside it and then just return `urlRequest` instance.